# Create log spaced numbers in R with high upper bound

Tags: r

I want to create a set of 10 logspaced numbers from zero to some big number M, say M=60,000, for example in R.

First, I tried to use `lseq()` from the package `emdbook`. The problem with `lseq`, however, is that it cannot handle 0 as a starting point. (This is due to the fact that it will try to calculate log(0) and then fail).

Next, I tried to use `logspace()` from the `pracma` package in the following way:

```
Numbers <- log(logspace(0,M,10),base=10)
```

This works fine for values of M up to about 340. From then on the numbers in the set will become infinity because the exponential function becomes too large.

Is there any other way in R to create a set of logspaced numbers from zero to some big number M which will not make most of the numbers in the set infinity and which can actually handle zero as a starting point?

Comment: Obviously, `log(logspace(0, M, 10),base=10)` is the same as `linspace(0, M, 10)`, so what is the problem? Example: `linspace(0, 600, 9)` results in `0  75 150 225 300 375 450 525 600`, `log(logspace(0,600,9),base=10)` in `0  75 150 225 300 Inf Inf Inf Inf`.

Comment: Thank you very much @HansW.! Sometimes things can be so easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but can't you just çalculate the logspaces for lower numbers and then multiply? They should be linearly related right? Just look at this output:

```
library(pracma)
> log(logspace(0,60, 10), base = 10)[1:5]
[1]  0.000000000000000  6.666666666666667 13.333333333333334 20.000000000000000 26.666666666666668
> log(logspace(0,600, 10), base = 10)[1:5]
[1]   0.000000000000000  66.666666666666671 133.333333333333343 200.000000000000000 266.666666666666686

> x1 <- (log(logspace(0,600, 10), base = 10)*100)[2]
> x1
[1] 6666.666666666667
> x2 <- seq(0 , 9, 1)*x1
> x2
 [1]     0.000000000000  6666.666666666667 13333.333333333334 20000.000000000000 26666.666666666668
[6] 33333.333333333336 40000.000000000000 46666.666666666672 53333.333333333336 60000.000000000000
```